# speed up Matrix Multiplication by SSE2

Tags: c, matrix, simd, intrinsics, sse2

I want to know how speed up matrix multiplication by SSE2

here is my code

```
int mat_mult_simd(double *a, double *b, double *c, int n)
{
   __m128d c1,c2,a1,a2,b1;

   for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<n/2; j++){
          c1 = _mm_load_pd(c+(2*j*n)+(i+2));
          c2 = _mm_load_pd(c+n+(2*j*n)+(i+2));
          for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
             a1 = _mm_load1_pd(a+k+(2*j*n));
             a2 = _mm load1_pd(a+n+k+(2*j*n));
             b1 = _mm_load_pd(b+(k*n)+(i*2));
             c1 = _mm_add_pd(c1, _mm_mul_pd(a1,b1));
             c2 = _mm_add_pd(c2, _mm_mul_pd(a2,b1));
          }
          __mm_store_pd(c+(2*j*n)+(i+2), c1);
          __mm_store_pd(c+n+(2*j*n)+(i+2), c2);
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

each parameter means

'a' = vector a(MAT_SIZE*MAT_SIZE)

'b' = vector b(MAT_SIZE*MAT_SIZE)

'c' = vector c(MAT_SIZE*MAT_SIZE)

'n' = MAT_SIZE is constant (It always even and >=2)

this code speed up about X4. against

```
int mat_mult_default(double *a, double *b, double *c, int n)
{
 double t;
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
    t=0.0;
    for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
       t += a[i*n+k] * b[k*n+j];
    c[i*n+j] = t;
    }
 }
}
```

but I want to more speed up. I usually experiment MAT_SIZE 1000*1000 or 2000*2000.
how can i speed up? Is there other way to indexing? I really want to know. thanks.

Comment: -1 It is unrealistic to just demand better performance without giving any reason where it might come from. It is also unreasonable to state that code is 4 times faster than something without specifying what that something is. You need to do a lot more effort to ask a precise and specific question. You need to provide complete benchmarking programs that make it clear where your figures come from. You need to supply typical matrix sizes, sample data and so on.

Comment: -1 Why should you write such basic routines yourself? Use a library like Intel MKL. If it is for you to learn SSE, please add this.

Comment: @user2799037 What's wrong with writing low level code? Every decent video encoders/decoders use their own SIMD assembly for instance

Comment: @z̫͋ Low level code is only useful if you know what you do. And if there are already highly optimized routines available, why not using them?

Comment: To build the optimized function, I had to make changes. First, my gcc compiler has no __mm_store_pd, so I used _mm_store_pd. But then I got alignment faults, so I changed it to _mm_storeu_pd. Is the example code pasted in correctly? Another problem. It looks to me like the optimized function never writes to element 0,0 of the result array.

Comment: You appear to be new to SO. Let me give you some advice. Search for the SSE tags and click on votes to sort by highest votes. Read through the quests and answers. You can narrow your search by adding matrix multiplication for example. You can learn a lot doing this (more than from many books) and probably answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few things. The obvious one is splitting the work into several threads (1 per core). You can use OpenMP (easiest), Intel TBB or other multithreading libs.
This will provide a significant improvement on a multi-core machine.

Another thing is to looks at the disassembly (via your favorite debugger) - look how the compiler handles all the multiplications you use for the indexes, some of them can be eliminated.

Your code does 2 computations in one loop, try to do more 4 or 8 to have better locality. E.g. a1 and a2 couldbe calculated with their neighbors who are already in the L1 cache. You can actually loads them with a single load operation.

Make sure the various arrays are SSE aligned (16 Byte) and change your code to use aligned reads/writes.

I'd leave multithreading to the end as finding bugs is harder.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the right library like the Intel Math Kernel Library or a similar highly optimized linear algebra package (OpenBLAS, AMD Core Math Library, ATLAS, ...). They are considered faster compared hand-written code. They have sometimes even processor-specific optimizations for instruction sets and cache sizes. And they are professionals in their field. Unless you plan to publish a paper on your own optimization, the go with the library.

In the [latest issue](http://www.heise.de/ct/inhalt/2014/12/176/) of the German computer magazine c't they claim the compiler is smart enough to use SSE or AVX by itself. Just write the right loops and the auto-vectorizer will bring the best results. This is true for the latest Intel compiler. Microsoft's compiler are too dump. In some cases with the right compiler flags, Intel's compiler even detects that you program a matrix multiplication and replaces this by the right call. Or you have to check the documentation, it is not that hard to learn such a package.

Comment: I don't think this is a very good answer at all. Can you explain how MKL will do better than the code in the question?

Comment: Sure, most mainstream compilers today can auto-vectorize. But it doesn't mean they actually do a good job of it. The gap between auto-vectorization and manual vectorization by an experienced programmer is still very large. Part of the reason is that the programmer has domain-specific knowledge that the compiler does not.

Comment: I don't know how to use MKL yet. I want to know is that there will be another way to indexing.

Comment: @Mysticial The source I referred to states quite the opposite. It claims that MKL beats the hand-written code (sorry that it is only in German). If you have domain-specific knowledge, you should use that to select a better solving method as there are a bunch of optimized special cases. So this is not an argument.

Comment: @user2799037 The MKL is hand written by Intel employees (probably hand-optimized assembly). So of course they can do better than the average programmer. They know their processors better than anyone else.

Comment: Besides "promo" constituent of "Use Compiler or Library" answer, there is one very pragmatic point: low-level intrinsics/assembly codes are never really portable - you need to rewrite them again and again - for every new platform and for every new "unexpected" workload/environment. And of course I don't agree with "don't do good job" statement: there are enough mechanisms to "push" and "tweak" good compiler or library in order to do just excellent job nowadays. Of course these "compiler/lib tweakings" also require some expertise, but they are still much cheaper and usually 100% portable.

Comment: Off topic: it's important to remember that "good intrinsics " vs. "good library/compiler" discussions are never completely neutral. 1) Intrinsics experts are often motivated to ban Compilers/Libs, because Compilers/Libs are dangerous for their "job security": every time new platform comes - they have more job and more clients. 2) On the other hand Compiler/Libs developers are also getting their salary with help of Compiler/Lib/Hardware sales. 3) Of course, there are also some really neutral enthusiasts and professionals, but you never know the real motivation from forum for sure..